# How to Update a Table for a same matching row

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor, row, dbms-scheduler

I have a Table TBLmaterial where current Stock is defined for particular Materailid .

[image]

And i have a tbldrawingtable where required quantity is listed for a particular material . It should update present column as required quantity and status to Available if current stock is available .

for example : Materialid =2 have 4 requiredQTY in 102=drawid and 2 requiredQTY in 105=drawid . IT should update because total 6 CurrentStock is present for the material id 2.

[image]

As per latest update of code .below result will displayed which is correct.

[image]

If i check for material id 1 once again . it should update drawing id 107 for the material id 1 to Not available because no more current stock is available to update . 
my code below :

```
 Alter procedure dbo.FetchInto(@Matid int)
 as
 begin

 declare @CurrentStock int
 declare @required Int
 declare @present int

 select @CurrentStock=M.CurrentStock
 from Tblmaterial M
 inner join
 TblDrawingTable D
 on M.Matid=D.Matid
 where M.Matid =@Matid


select top 1 @required=d.RequiredQty from Tblmaterial M
inner join
TblDrawingTable D
on M.Matid=D.Matid
 where m.Matid =@Matid

select  top 1 @present=(m.CurrentStock-isnull(d.Present,0)) 
from TblDrawingTable D
inner join
Tblmaterial M
on D.Matid=m.Matid
where D.Matid=@Matid


if exists(select 1 from TblDrawingTable where Matid=@Matid and Present is 
null)
begin
if (@required<=@CurrentStock and @present >0)
UPDATE TblDrawingTable SET present=@required,status='Available' where Drawid 
= (select top 1 Drawid from TblDrawingTable where
Matid=@Matid) and Matid=@Matid
end    
else if(@present=@required)
update TblDrawingTable SET status='Not Available',Present=@present where  
Drawid <> (select top 1 Drawid from TblDrawingTable where
Matid=@Matid) and Matid=@Matid


 if exists(select 1 from TblDrawingTable where Matid=@Matid and Present is 
 null)
 begin
if (@required<=@CurrentStock and @present>0)
UPDATE TblDrawingTable SET present=(@CurrentStock-
@required),status='Available' where  Drawid <> (select top 1 Drawid from 
TblDrawingTable where
Matid=@Matid) and Matid=@Matid
end    
else if(@present=@required) 
update TblDrawingTable SET status='Not Available',Present=@present where  
Matid=@Matid
end
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: ya done jarlh..

Comment: Perhaps sql-server instead?

Comment: ok done jarlh..

Comment: By the way, using cursors in SQL should always be the very last resource

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check your code, but if I understood correctly you need to:

- collect all the existing material from drawings
- compare with in stock
- update consequentially

I would work with CTE

Edit:
I add some partial code that can be used to solve the issue

```
;WITH ExistingMat AS (
  SELECT Matid, SUM(RequiredQty) ExistingQty
  FROM TBLDrawing
  GROUP BY Matid
),
CompareMat AS (
  SELECT m.*, ISNULL(e.ExistingQty, 0) ExistingQty
  FROM TBLMaterial m LEFT OUTER JOIN ExistingMat e ON m.Matid = e.Matid
)
SELECT d.*, c.CurrentStock, c.ExistingQty, CASE WHEN c.ExistingQty <= c.CurrentStock THEN 'Available' ELSE 'Not Available' END UpdStatus, ExistingQty UpdPresent
FROM TBLDrawing d INNER JOIN CompareMat c ON d.Matid = c.Matid
```

Comment: how to compare Individually please help me Simone

Comment: its not existing.. its required qnty

Comment: are you referring to the names? Feel free to change them as you like

Comment: No .just Material ID

Comment: sorry I don't understand, please reformulate with more details

Comment: hi Simone . i have modified the code . please have a check . It should update present column as required quantity and status to Available if current stock is available .

Comment: Hi Sampath, sorry but I cannot check your code just on the assumption "it should update". In my humble opinion that would be your task, and only after not being successful you can try to ask for help clarifying what you've done and where it is not working

Comment: I have modified by checking for different condition for current stock, required stock, present stock.for example:If i check for material id 1 once again . it should update drawing id 107 for the material id 1 to Not available because no more current stock is available to update . my code below :

Comment: Hi Sampath, the first thing that jumps to my eyes is this: "select @required=RequiredQty from TblDrawingTable where Matid =@Matid" You are just getting the required quantity for one random row instead of summing up all the needed one as per the first rows of my code

Comment: second, in the main part you check for present to be null and then compare it to numbers????

Comment: third, what does this aim to: "select top 1  @present=(m.CurrentStock-d.Present)" ---- random result from the whole table

Comment: general considerations, choose a typing  style (Capital or not) and  adhere to that, indent correctly your code

Comment: hi simone. Ya i will check for @required by summing . Thank you

Comment: first time i will check for null to update first row of every first material id. that is updated as top 1 . then i am greater than zero , that is something is updated greater than zero to check for second row of same material id

Comment: 80 % but failing in one scenario . please find modified Code .